# Linker warning C++ Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++

I have run into this problem, which although is a warning, I suspect is a sign of something wrong under the hood. When I build in release mode I get this warning:

> MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrtd.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

I'm building a dynamic DLL in [Visual Studio C++ Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.2B.2B_Express). When I do it in debug mode no warning arises. I've googled a bit and it looks like `msvcrt` and `msvcrtd` are both for multithreading, one for debugging and the other not. I could use `/NODEFAULTLIB` with `MSVCRT.lib`, but I don't think that avoiding symptoms really helps with the problem.

I really don't know if this is a huge problem. The DLL and `.lib` files are generated correctly.

Comment: The release version should include only `msvcrt.lib` and not `msvcrtd.lib`. Are you sure you did not add something by mistake?

Comment: I see that you are new here. If any of the answers below help fix your problem, then please mark the answer as "accepted". :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge problem, since it can lead to many unexpected crashes of your application, AND you can't distribute an application which links `msvcrtd.lib`, since you are not allowed to distribute the debug C++ runtimes of Visual Studio.
Though `/NODEFAULTLIB` should fix those, you should fix the issue itself.

Like casablanca said, `msvcrtd.lib` is linked in release mode, but it should only be linked in debug mode.
This does not mean that your own application has wrong linker settings. Any of the libraries you use in your project could have incorrect settings as well.

What I usually do to fix this is, to open all the release `.lib` files which your application links, with a text editor which can open such large binary files (like [SciTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE)), and then I search them for e.g. `VC80.DebugCRT` (VC80 == Visual Studio 2005 in this case), and if I find this string in one of those libraries, that library should be recompiled with `/MD`.

If you are linking dynamic libraries, you can use a tool called [Dependency Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) on the `.dll` files instead of manually searching the `.lib` files. 
If Dependency Walker shows the dependency on one of the debug crt DLL files like e.g. `MSVCP80D.dll` (note the trailing D), recompile that library using `/MD`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to your libraries.
They are linked differently than your program.

Your program may be single-threaded, while your libraries may be linked as multithreaded, for example.

Look under

```
Project Properties 
Configuration Properties
C/C++ 
Code Generation 
Runtime Library
```

to see the setting (e.g. "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)").

Answer (score 0):

Check that your runtime library settings are correct in the Release configuration of your project.  Basically it should be the same as your Debug build, but without the word 'Debug' in the description.  Visual Studio docs on this issue are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Check your settings as follows:

- in Solution Explorer right click the Project and select Properties
- make sure the Configuration (at the top of the Properties window) is `Active (Release)`
- go to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation
- check that Runtime Library for Release is not a `Debug` version of the CRT.